# How to check whether password match or not using primeface?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

How can I check whether password match or not in primefaces? I am using primeface tag p:password but upon enter different mpin on both fields (new mpin and confirm mpin) it is not showing or updating error i.e mpin does not match. It show validation message after submit not on key up event

Here is my code

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <p:outputLabel class="require-field"
                                           value="New MPIN"
                                           for="newMpin"></p:outputLabel>
                            <p:password type="text" id="newMpin"
                                        class="numbersOnly" maxlength="4"
                                        placeholder="Enter New Mpin"
                                        required="true"
                                        autocomplete="new-password"
                                        match="reEnterNewMpin"
                                        validatorMessage="#{msg.msgNewMpinMatch}"
                                        requiredMessage="#{msg.msgNewMpinValid}"
                                        value="#{changeMPINBean.mpin.newMPIN}">
                                <p:keyFilter regEx="/[0-9]/i"
                                             preventPaste="false"></p:keyFilter>
                                <f:validateRegex pattern="^[0-9]{4}$">
                                </f:validateRegex>
                                <p:ajax event="keyup" execute="@this" update="reEnterNewMpinMessage newMpinMessage"/>
                            </p:password>
                            <p:message for="newMpin" id="newMpinMessage"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <p:outputLabel class="require-field"
                                           value="Confirm New MPIN"
                                           for="reEnterNewMpin"></p:outputLabel>
                            <p:password type="text" id="reEnterNewMpin"
                                        class="numbersOnly" maxlength="4"
                                        placeholder="Confirm New Mpin"
                                        required="true"
                                        autocomplete="new-password"
                                        validatorMessage="#{msg.msgNewConfirmMpinMatch}"
                                        requiredMessage="#{msg.msgNewConfirmMpinValid}"
                                        value="#{changeMPINBean.mpin.newMPIN}">
                                <p:keyFilter regEx="/[0-9]/i"
                                             preventPaste="false"></p:keyFilter>
                                <f:validateRegex pattern="^[0-9]{4}$">
                                </f:validateRegex>
                                <p:ajax event="keyup" execute="@this" update="reEnterNewMpinMessage newMpinMessage"/>
                            </p:password>
                            <p:message for="reEnterNewMpin" id="reEnterNewMpinMessage"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
  <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-field">

                            <p:commandButton value="Submit" id="createUserButton"
                                             styleClass="btn btn-md btn-wide btn-submit"
                                             actionListener="#{changeMPINBean.changeMPINFunctionality()}"
                                             onstart="ajaxFadeIn();" oncomplete="ajaxFadeOut();"
                                             update="userForm">
                            </p:commandButton>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Gif is also attached for

[image: reference]

Comment: There is an example of password matching right on the showcase: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/password.xhtml  But that is for submit it checks in the JSF validation phase.   You will need to custom code this behavior with Javascript `onkeyup`

Comment: You aren't checking if those MPINs are equal, you just put the same value to both `p:password`, so the result you get is correct, try as @Melloware suggests